# Different url for modules in Zend2

Tags: url, module, zend-framework2

I'm having a problem with Zend Framework 2.2, I have my project and a module called 'app'. Everything is working fine, when I go to "myurl.com/app" I see my module and everything ok.

Now I want to have a url "app.myurl.com" that shows my module "app" instead of the previous url myurl.com/app.
How do i need to configure to get this?
Please anybody help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want it's a subdomain that maps ZF2 module from your project. 
I think, you could set this rather on the server side then ZF2.

Comment: but what is the path of a submodule index? I mean if my index page is at path myproject/public, for a submodule index what it should be?